# sendmail not working

Tags: debian, sendmail, chroot

I'm trying to use the `mail()` function in PHP on a Debain Linux server.

I have 2 web servers running. One is in a chrooted setup.

The server that's not chrooted works fine, the other one wont send email.

Any idea how I can setup emailing in the chrooted setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses the external sendmail program to send E-mail messages ([1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), [2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path)). To avoid installing it in its entirety in the chroot jail, lightweight programs exist that can provide the necessary functionality within the jail. [How-tos for setting this up](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+mail+function+chroot) exist.

- [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) (available from Debian; binaries available)
- [mini_sendmail](http://www.acme.com/software/mini_sendmail/) (not available from Debian; must be compiled from source)
- See also a full list of [light SMTP agents](http://wiki.mutt.org/?LightSMTPagents) as well as [other mail-related programs Debian offers](http://packages.debian.org/stable/mail/).

Comment: Thanks, I found this link after searching some of this information. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-setup-sendmail-php-mail-chrooted-apache-lighttpd.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a small utility called "mail" or "email" or something like that, which can be installed as a simple replacement for sendmail, postfix, qmail, ... Just install to the chrooted environment and redirect the mails to the mailserver outside the jail.